# Android Activity Cycle? Text Remains When Activity is destroyed like Whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-savedstate

I am new to Android and recently focusing on the Activity cycle.
My understanding is that if we destroy an activity class, all the unsaved data will be cleared.

But whatsapp's chat page seems to be quite interesting as after I quit the chat page and re-enter that particular chat page, I would see the unsaved text remain in the edittext box.

So, how would they do the tricks? Is it related to "savedInstanceState" ?

[image]

Comment: Are you minimising the screen or are you pressing back button?

Comment: Its done by saving the widget status on leaving the screen and reloading it when screen is loaded again.

Comment: Just tested on mine.  Remove the App from Recent ones list and the text does not stay. That mean text is not saved in some persistent storage.

Comment: `savedInstanceState` is used only when activity is not destroyed, i mean when there are orientation changes. but whatsapp may be using preferences or DB to persist this data even when the activity is destroyed. Everytime the activity is loaded it checks whether the persisted data is available, if it is available then is retains it in respective widgets.

Comment: Thanks all of you!
@AmrutBidri: i agree with you! savedInstanceState would not do the trick. I guess they use db to hold the text as if i repeat this action in different chat accounts, i would get the same result so i guess using "shared preference" will be a bit difficult to handle multi-accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the comments from Scion of Ikshvaku
I created a sqlite table to store the unsent msg in edittext.
It would achieve the same result as whatsapp. The trick indeed is not difficult

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that if we destroy an activity class, all the unsaved data will be cleared.

Yes unless of course important data is saved in some persistent storage in `onPause()` method and retrieved in `onResume()` method. This is common way to persist data when Activity is killed by used or OS and restarted later.

> But whatsapp's chat page seems to be quite interesting as after i quit the chat page and re-enter that particular chat page, i would see the unsaved text remain in the edittext box.

This is the case when you click back button and go to the chat page again. I confirmed that this is not the case when you kill the app itself. So a good guess would be the activity is never killed and the data is persisted via `savedInstanceState`.

Answer (score 0):

In normal cases, when you click `Back` button of your device, life span method `onPause` would be called. Maybe WhatsApp stores the text from the `EditText` into `SharedPreference`. When you go to this `Activity` again, text of this `EditText` would be set as the text stored into `SharedPreference`. Of course, in this case of `WhatsApp`, only its developers know.